# Fetch follower list using Twitter new Rest API v1.1 in ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

When I am fetching the follower List using the new API I am getting response: 
    { errors = ( { code = 215; message = "Bad Authentication data"; } ); }

The Request I am sending is:

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=ImpressolTest&count=5000`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, Twitter v1.1 requires authentication.. The result you're getting says it all..

Comment: Thank You for the response.It means that we can't see the contents of the url through address bar as we used to see.Only we have to go through the coding if we have to check the contents of url.Can you please give any link or related sample code of authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch Followers List by using Twitter v1.1

https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine  by using FHSTwitterEngine

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json

use this